# Dont work coffeescript method change text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5 beta3

I installed gems

```
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
```

Created script: **javascripts/freelancers.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('.birthday1').change ->
    alert( "Alert!!!!!!!!" )
    $('.birthday1').datepicker()
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<li>
        <label for="freelancer_birth_date">Birthday</label>
        <div>          
          <%= f.text_field :birthday, class: 'birthday1' %>
        </div>
      </li>
```

I input new value in text field, but nothing happen. What is incorrect in my script?

Comment: Is `freelancers.coffee` included in your `application.js` file?

Comment: i added //= require freelancers. Now calling alert. Thank you.

Comment: I think, you should use `id: 'birthday1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with conflict with another jquery scripts. I deleted this scripts and all are working now.